# SQL select previous record where

Tags: mysql, select, join

So I am trying to query through a table, call it students
if the column "status" in Student is 'active', then select the "firstName" and "lastName" coloumns from the previous record. Each record has a primary key.
That is, if the "status" column of record is =active, then, i want to select the previos record.
The table is already populated with data like

```
id  firstname   lastname    status          email
9   Joe         Peters      inactive        fp@gmail.com
10  kim         Rol         active          rt@yh.com
11  Lance       Ree         inactive        lll&hh.com
12  diana       Jones       active          sams@yahoo.com
```

For this data,the query should return Joe peters and lance ree
How can i do this? 
thanks

Comment: There is no "previous record" in `SQL`. Previous in which order?

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do on a higher level? Maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: It would help if you could draw out the data in a table so we can see what you are looking for.  If you really mean select the previous row if the status column='active' then you might have seriously wrong with your design.

Comment: Hypothesis: after a SELECT query, he wants to go back in the result set :-?

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario I hope not, but expect the worst ,)

Comment: So if id 10 is active, you want Joe Peters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to select name from the records where the student is `active`, the query is a simple

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname
FROM students
WHERE status = "active"
```

I assume what you mean by *previous row* is *the row you just determined was an active student*. The query will check your table for active students and retrieve their names. Because names are very rarely unique, I included the ID column.
I also recommend setting the status column to a 0 or 1 integer.

If you really want to select the previous row, you can use

```
SELECT sj.id, sj.firstname, sj.lastname
FROM students AS s
LEFT JOIN students AS sj ON (sj.id = s.id - 1)
WHERE s.status = "active"
```

The point is in determining the relation between the rows you have and the rows you want to select. In this case, you want to select the row which has the ID 1 less than your current row. Since this constraint is very restrictive, it's not a good idea to select rows this way. You might want to redesign your database.

Comment: Also, your active students are Kim Rol and Diana Jones.  If you want Joe Peters and Lance Ree set `status = "inactive"`

Comment: thank you. this is just an example, I want to know if it is possible/if there is a short way to select some previous record based on the current one

Comment: This only works when you don't have gaps in your id column from deleting records, etc.

Comment: Yes, it works with the given constraint of ID 1 less. If you'd want to extend to allow gaps, you'd need to change it to get the ID value from something like a subquery that `(SELECT MAX(id) FROM students WHERE id < s.id)`. The problem is, you can have an arbitrary number of such extensions, each more complex than the last. Thus, it's a bad idea to try and select rows this way.

Answer (score 0):

With previous record you probably mean the priviously inserted one. you can refer to that row using [last_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) - which is a mysql-function -  that will return the last inserted auto-incremented value.

```
select * from T where id = last_insert_id();
```